# Stripe charge same plan multiple times

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe.net

I have to charge my clients monthly depending on how many users they have.

So, I've created a plan to charge the user 10€/monthly but it only charges him once, and I've to charge it 10€monthly/user so, if he has 5users, I need to charge 50€/monthly.

I could assign 10 times the same plan but... I don't think this is the "proper way" to achieve this.

Any way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update the subscription with `quantity` field set to the number of users whenever the number of users changes.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/curl#update_subscription